# Recording Sound or Images Using Azure IoT Central

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I plan on creating an IoT device which consists of various sensors, but two important sensors are a microphone and a video camera, which intermittently takes images. The microphone I can do without, but the video camera is very important as I use it together with a downstream ML model to recognize certain defects and needs for maintenance.

I cannot immediately see any availability of sending images (or even video streams) to Azure IoT Central. I am therefore curious if I am missing something? If not, is there a workaround this?

I tried searching on Google, reading the docs and looking at the Azure IoT Central dashboard/UI.

Answer (score 1):

I guess **IoT Central provides support for telemetry data, including properties and events, but it does not directly support sending images or video streams as part of the telemetry data.**

Let me give you a work around -
set your IoT device to capture images or video frames using the camera sensor.
Use Azure IoT Hub to send metadata associated with the captured images or video frames to Azure IoT Central. such as timestamps, device IDs,etc

Set up an Azure Storage account eg like a blob stotage to store the actual image or video data. When the device captures an image or frame, upload the data to Azure Storage and obtain a reference URL.

Send the reference URLs or identifiers of the stored images or video frames to Azure IoT Central as telemetry data. Integrate your downstream ML model with Azure Functions that processes the stored images or video frames from Azure Storage.